Problem Load Testing Apache Jmeter ALB AWS EC2 Auto Scaling
I ran a JMeter test with 16,400 threads, a 30-second ramp-up, and GET request type to the ALB DNS for the React frontend, without connecting to the database or backend. Why are there no errors at 16,400 threads, but errors appear at 16,450, even though CPU utilization, network in, and memory are all low? I'm confused about what parameter is causing the error.
I've also tried increasing the number of instances from 2 to 4, but the error remains the same.

We cannot help you without knowing the details of the "error" you're getting.
16000 users is quite a big number, you need to at least tune JMeter properly and do the same on the operating system level in terms of ephemeral ports and sockets timeouts

Thank you. The error I'm encountering is related to the HTTP request failing after I pass 16,400 threads, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact cause. The error message in JMeter shows a connection timeout.
Could you please clarify what specific tuning I should focus on in JMeter and what changes I might need on the operating system level regarding ephemeral ports and socket timeouts? I'm running this on AWS EC2
I haven't made any adjustments to these settings yet, so any pointers on how to approach them would be very helpful.
